# PHP - Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object - Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm having an issue with the prepared statement below:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_token WHERE token = ".$token."");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $token);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

If I run the following against the database, everything works fine and it returns the one row. I've tried to do a

```
var_dump($stmt);
```

and that returned:

```
bool(false)
```

So that means that the query is failing, but I'm really not sure why. Maybe someone could have a look and tell me where I'm going wrong with this.

P.S. There is a token in the database. The same token is in the URL. I get the token from the URL successfully. I tried echo and it displayed fine. Then I am just trying to retrieve the row that contains the token from URL from the database, but it's failing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you are binding, you are providing directly value in query,instead put a placeholder in query.

Comment: The token in the query and the token in the bind_param are different, should I name the parameter differently?